# MySQL Sum of IF statement

Tags: mysql, count, sum, case

So far I have this working query that sums the number of inspections Grouped By serial number and then subtracts the sum of those that Passed Inspection ('P'). If the number of passes equals the number of inspections then this is considered an overall pass and we assign a value of 1 otherwise 0.

```
SELECT IF(SUM(CASE 
             WHEN i.inspect_result IN ('P','F') THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) -

        SUM(CASE 
             WHEN i.inspect_result ='P' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END)=0,1,0) as Results 

 FROM inspections i WHERE workorder_id=5 GROUP BY serial_no
```

This yields a result like so

```
-------------
Results
-------------
1
0
1
1
0
0
1
1
1
0
etc.
```

What I want to do is SUM the Results.  I tried encapsulating the entire query with **SELECT SUM(*existing query*)** but cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(Results)
FROM (
SELECT IF(SUM(CASE 
             WHEN i.inspect_result IN ('P','F') THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) -

        SUM(CASE 
             WHEN i.inspect_result ='P' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END)=0,1,0) as Results 

 FROM inspections i WHERE workorder_id=5 GROUP BY serial_no
) a
```

Here is the simple **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/367ad/4/0)**.